# Count Column in SharePoint List

Tags: calculated-column

I am trying to add a column that counts every time a date column is amended past the current date stored by more than 7 days.

Column A would be a Project Live Date which isn't a fixed date column so would move dependent on the project - I'm trying to add the count to see how many times this date is modified past the date.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Calculated columns in SharePoint does not allow updating a Date column when the day goes off. Which means that is static.

1. So an option would be creating a timerjob which runs every midnight and update the list column.
2. Else you can create a content query webpart which has an XSLT(type of XML) template. In that you can customize the template and make another appear like a column. Here you may have to use some jQuery if you are to give the OOTB filtering and sorting.

Comment: You can get the data for this by enabling versioning and counting the amount of versions from x date on.

Comment: One thing I do not like about versioning is that it consumes more and more storage. In a situation where the user does not need to track exactly what changed, I would prefer something simple like this.

Comment: I'm talking about the data, a timer job can't know how many times something has changed without some kind of data. I guesse you can also use the audit trail for it if you want the storage footprint to be small but I think you'd have to read SQL directly. If it's a simple counter you're better off using a modify event receiver.